# Rotate an Object on X and Z GLOBAL axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have the following scenario:

I have a cylinder in my scene and I hace two Dropdowns. With the Dropdowns, I can select a rotation on X and Z axis of either 0 or 90 degrees. This rotation always has to be on the global axis so the user understands whats happening.

When i rotate the object 90deg on the X axis, everything is ok. When i try to rotate it by 90deg on the Z axis aditionally, the object is being rotated around the Y axis, not the Z axis.

I have tried to do with with setting transform.rotation directly, transform.Rotate and transform.RotateAround but nothing worked.

The first thing I do is always resetting the rotation to 0.

```cs
Object.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
```

My Try with Eulers:

```cs
Object.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(xRot, 0, zRot));
```

My Try with Quaternions:

```cs
Object.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(xRot * 90, Vector3.right) * Quaternion.AngleAxis(zRot * 90, Vector3.forward);
```

My Try with Rotate:

```cs
Object.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(xRot, 0, zRot), Space.World);
```

My expected result is the object to always rotate around the GLOBAL X/Z axis, no matter what the objects current rotation might be. But none of my tries resulted in the expected behaviour.

Comment: `Object.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;` is actually redundand except you want to use `Rotate`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
gameObject.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(xRot, 0, zRot);
```

Or this for global axis:

```
gameObject.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(xRot, 0, zRot);
```

Comment: `gameObject.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(xRot, 0, zRot);` basically equals `Object.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(xRot, 0, zRot));`